# Implementation of substring in C# and which algorithm does it use?

Tags: java, c#, performance, algorithm, substring

I have a question, i'm doing some research on some programming languages.
The research is about the efficiency of the substring functions in C# and Java.

Questions like is C# using a brute force kind of way, or do they implement Boyer-Moore's algorithm like a good boy. 
I need the source code for this, I already found it for Java ( Who use a brute force implementation in the indexOf()method for those who wonder ).

Does anyone have an idea how i can retrieve the source code for methods like these in C#.
I have visual studios installed on my laptop but i can't find any source code...

Your help will much obliged!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microsoft has published the complete framework source code, including comments. You will find the actual implementation [over here on referencesource](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,882fa7998d6ca35a). For `SubString`, it comes down to some unmanaged code:

```
    [System.Security.SecurityCritical]  // auto-generated
    unsafe string InternalSubString(int startIndex, int length) {
        Contract.Assert( startIndex >= 0 && startIndex <= this.Length, "StartIndex is out of range!");
        Contract.Assert( length >= 0 && startIndex <= this.Length - length, "length is out of range!");            

        String result = FastAllocateString(length);

        fixed(char* dest = &result.m_firstChar)
            fixed(char* src = &this.m_firstChar) {
                wstrcpy(dest, src + startIndex, length);
            }

        return result;
```

As you can see, they are using wstrcpy which probably is as fast as it gets.

Comment: Thanks you so much! No idea they released it cause it always was closed source.

Comment: @user1758777 Making .NET open source is a very recent development--in the last two months.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/11/12/net-core-is-open-source.aspx.